# Date/Time data types and declaration in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, timestamp

I would like to have a date and time column in my table. The main purpose of having these 2 columns is to be able to return query results like:

1. Number of treatments done in the period `November 2011`.
2. Number of people working in shifts between `00:01` and `08:00` hours.

I have two tables, which have the following attributes in them(among others):

```
 Shift(day, month, year)
 Treatment(start_time, date)
```

1. For the first table- Shift, query results need to return values in
   terms of (ex: December 30,2012)
2. For the second table, start_time needs to have values like 0001 and
   0800(as I mentioned above). While, date can return values like
   'November 2011'.

Initially I thought using the `date` datatype for declaring each of the `day/month/year/date` variables would do the job. But this doesn't seem to work out. Should I use `int`, `varchar` and `int` respectively for `day`, `month` and `year` respectively? Also, since the `date` variable does not have component parts, will `date` datatype work here? Lastly, if I use `timestamp` data type for the `start_time` attribute, what should be the value I enter in the insert column- should it be `08:00:00?`

I'm using `SQL Server 2014`.

Thank You for your help.

Comment: The date type should work fine for the first part. What"doesn't work out"?

Comment: Oh, and don't use timestamp unless you really know what it does, because it's probably not what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it is better to use one column by type of DateTime instead of two columns which hold Date and Time separately.

Also you could simply query this column either by Date or Time by casting it to corresponding type :

```
DECLARE @ChangeDateTime AS DATETIME = '2012-12-09 16:07:43.937'
SELECT CAST(@ChangeDateTime AS DATE) AS [ChangeDate],
       CAST(@ChangeDateTime AS TIME) AS [ChangeTime]
```

results to :

```
ChangeDate      ChangeTime
----------    ----------------
2012-12-09    16:07:43.9370000
```